# How to keep backward compatibility in React Native?

Tags: react-native

For example in React Native 0.44 `BackAndroid` becomes deprecated and `BackHandler` should be used instead. Inside project it's not a problem to upgrade React Native and replace `BackAndroid` with `BackHandler`.

But what if I am writing a public library? I want to keep compatibility with React Native < 0.44 and avoid warning about deprecation in 0.44. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot answer this fully, I'd like to suggest you to simply cut off support for older RN versions as your library keeps up with the [all the React Native changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases).

This is both for your sanity and for the fact that it's a common practice to drop support for particular versions as things break. [`0.40.0`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases?after=v0.42.0-rc.0) was a great example of that.

Nevertheless, in this very case `0.44.0` [still supports](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b7e9374c649a8e08108ec3165d68d009b88f0dec) `BackAndroid` so instead of forcing users to upgrade, you may want to recommend using:

`console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: BackAndroid']`

in their apps as a temporary workaround to get rid of the depreciation warning.